# Disabling options won't work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

in my case I am trying to check if 3 different queries could be executed.

Depending on true or false (if / else), a jQuery script should be run to either enable or disable an `<option>` tag.

My problem is, whenever I run this code, either all `<option>` tags are disabled or they are all enabled.

**disable_options.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['first_field_selected'])) {
    $selected = $_POST['first_field_selected'];
    $output;
    // define unisolierte Systeme mit Einfachglas
    if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE $selected = 1 AND `unisolierte Systeme mit Einfachglas` = 1")) {
        $output .= '<script>$("#PG_Select_Bereich1 option[value=\'unisolierte Systeme mit Einfachglas\']").prop("disabled", false)</script>';
    }
    else { 
        $output .= '<script>$("#PG_Select_Bereich1 option[value=\'unisolierte Systeme mit Einfachglas\']").prop("disabled", true)</script>';
    }

    // define unisolierte Systeme mit Isolierglas
    if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE $selected = 1 AND `unisolierte Systeme mit Isolierglas` = 1")) {
        $output .= '<script>$("#PG_Select_Bereich1 option[value=\'unisolierte Systeme mit Isolierglas\']").prop("disabled", false)</script>';
    }
    else { 
        $output .= '<script>$("#PG_Select_Bereich1 option[value=\'unisolierte Systeme mit Isolierglas\']").prop("disabled", true)</script>';
    }

    // define isolierte Systeme bis Dreifachglas
    if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE $selected = 1 AND `isolierte Systeme bis Dreifachglas` = 1")) {
        $output .= '<script>$("#PG_Select_Bereich1 option[value=\'isolierte Systeme bis Dreifachglas\']").prop("disabled", false)</script>';
    }
    else { 
        $output .= '<script>$("#PG_Select_Bereich1 option[value=\'isolierte Systeme bis Dreifachglas\']").prop("disabled", true)</script>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="first_script"></div>
```

**script.js**

```
$.ajax({
     url : "typo3conf/ext/produkteguide_sg/pi1/disable_options.php",
     type: "POST",
     data : { first_field_selected: this.value },
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
     {
          $(".first_script").html(data);
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
     {
         alert(errorThrown);
     }
});
```

If you want to make yourself a picture, please go to [this page](http://mobileglas.tryit.ch/produkteguide) and select "Einbau in Fassade". You will see that on the next select field ALL options are disabled. In phpMyAdmin "Einbau in Fassade" (which is $selected) is set to 1, as you see in the image below.

[image]